# How to use RecoverableError to retry?

Tags: error-handling, swift3, nserror

In Swift 3, the [RecoverableError protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/recoverableerror) was introduced, but here is very little documentation on how to use this.

This sounds like a native way to offer retry functionality for failed processes, which could be pretty useful. What's an example of how this can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can utilize `RecoverableError` is Document-based application for macOS.

1. Create a new project, macOS > Cocoa, checking "Create Document-Based Application".
2. Define your own Error type conforming to `RecoverableError`.

   ```
   enum MyError {
       case documentSavingError
       //...
   }
   extension MyError: RecoverableError {
       var recoveryOptions: [String] {
           return [
               "Retry", "Ignore"
           ]
       }

       func attemptRecovery(optionIndex recoveryOptionIndex: Int) -> Bool {
           if recoveryOptionIndex == 0 {//for "Retry"
               var result = false
               switch self {
               case .documentSavingError:
                   //Attempt "Retry" recovery for the failed operation, and return the result
                   //...
                   print("assume recovery attempt successfully finished...")
                   result = true
               //...
               }
               return result
           } else if recoveryOptionIndex == 1 {//for "Ignore"
               return true
           }
           fatalError("something wrong...")
       }
   }
   ```
3. Modify the `data(ofType:)` method in Document.swift as to throw the error.

   ```
   override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {
       //throw RecoverableError
       throw MyError.documentSavingError
   }
   ```
4. You need one more trick in the current Document-based application...

   Create a new swift code to subclass `NSApplication`.

   ```
   import AppKit

   @objc(Application)
   class Application: NSApplication {
       override func presentError(_ error: Error, modalFor window: NSWindow, delegate: Any?, didPresent didPresentSelector: Selector?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
           //print(error)
           let underlyingError = (error as NSError).userInfo[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] as? Error ?? error
           //print(underlyingError)
           super.presentError(underlyingError, modalFor: window, delegate: delegate, didPresent: didPresentSelector, contextInfo: contextInfo)
       }
   }
   ```

   The current Document-based application wraps thrown `RecoverableError` in a usual `NSError`, so, without this, automatically generated `NSDocumentErrorRecoveryAttempter` does not work well.

   Do not forget to modify the Info.plist to designate this class as its Principal class.
5. Build and run the app, then when a document window is presented, File > Save..., and click Save in the save sheet.

   You may find how your `RecoverableError` is working...

---

So, `RecoverableError` is useful when your app already implements the standard recovery feature described in the [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806). And its Introduction says clearly:

> **Important**: The `NSError` class is available on both OS X and iOS. However, the error-responder and error-recovery APIs and mechanisms
>   are available only in the Application Kit (OS X).